# C++ strange output when adding integers or doubles together

Tags: c++, variables, integer, double

Im having a problem with adding numeric types together in c++ and cant figure out why its happening, I expect when I input 3 bowling scores together I will get 9 or 9.00, instead I get something crazy like 3.31748e+258, what am I doing wrong? any help will go a long way thanks!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>   
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
/*Coordinate variables*/
double bowlTotal;
double bowlScore;  
const int FIVE_PLAYERS = 5;

for( int players = 0; players < FIVE_PLAYERS ; players++ )
{
    cout << "Player " << players + 1 << endl << endl;

    for( int games = 0; games < 3; games++ )
    {

     double score;
     score = 0;

     cout << "Please enter score for game #" << games + 1<< ": ";
     cin >> score;
     cout << endl;

     bowlTotal += score;
    } 


     cout << endl << endl <<"The final score for player #"<< players + 1 << " = " << bowlTotal << endl << endl;
     bowlScore += bowlTotal;
}
cout << endl << endl <<"The final team score = " << bowlScore << endl << endl;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to initialize your variables to 0 before you use them, as shown below.

```
double bowlTotal = 0.0;
double bowlScore = 0.0;
```

Typically compiler will not do this for you, and the variables will be **filled with effectively garbage values**, to which you add your scores.

As GManNickG succinctly puts it, [**reading an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c).

Comment: More formally, reading an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help! knew it was something really silly lol

Answer (score 2):

You did not initialize bowlTotal or bowlScore, so they contain garbage.